# Does a Canadian, resident in the USA, need travel health insurance in Canada?

Tags: usa, canada, insurance

My girlfriend will be visiting Canada for about a month. Should we get health insurance? Is she covered in Canada?

Comment: Depends whether her current insurance covers external providers and what your risk profile is. Always safest to get travel insurance just to be on the safe side. It covers emergency evacuation, lost baggage, and more.

Comment: If you're asking if she has any coverage from Canada or its provinces, the answer is no.  Only residents get public health care benefits in Canada.  She'll need to buy insurance in the US to cover her in Canada, unless her existing health insurance is valid there and has adequate coverage.

Answer (score 4):

Insurance is about trading risk. If you feel it is needed to avoid worrying, then make sure she has some.

Canadian public insurance which varies by province is based on residency and so it is unlike that she will be covered by it. In Quebec for example, you have to reside 183 days per year to be covered. The rules are rather complex and there are exceptions such as while studying abroad.

She may be covered by insurance from the US already. There is usually a clause in health insurance that covers someone for a certain number of days outside of the country. It is usually a few weeks but that depends. Read the fine print of her insurance plan. Some credit-cards also add travel insurance, including health, when buying the full-price of the ticket with that card. Again, read the fine print.

Comment: She certainly won't be covered by any provincial or territorial plan in Canada.  Not only must she be resident, but there is a delay after taking residency and applying for coverage before coverage begins.

Answer (score 1):

First, check to see if she is covered under her US insurance (if she has any).

Many, but not all, US health insurance plans will provide coverage abroad. I'd check the fine print of the policy to see what coverage is offered and if it is adequate.